# Android Application crashes when I try to retrieve data from firebase

Tags: android

I created a simple sign up and successfully inserted data to the Firebase.
For now, I just want to use the email and a  password not encrypted to get a Name in fire base...I have tried but cant figure out how to do that....need some help. Here is a snapshot of the data I want to retrieve...
[image: test data]

Here is my code...

```
firebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, 
            String  previousChildKey) {

                  Sign login =snapshot.getValue(Sign.class);
                  snapshot.getKey();
                  String loginname= login.getName();
                  String loginemail = login.getEmail();
                  String loginpassword=login.getPassword();

                  if (loginemail==lemail loginpassword==loginpassword)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "All is good"+loginname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                  } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Please  check your Login Credentials or 
                             Login Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                         }
                  }                      
                });
```

Comment: If the app crashes, post the crash log. We can't guess what errors you get.

Comment: @TDG, The app shows zilwacom(appname) has stopped working